# Apply a list of function to parameter, clojure

Tags: clojure

```
(def ops '(+ - * /))
(map #(% 2 5) ops)
```

gives

```
(5 5 5 5)
```

This doesn't make sense to me. Why does this return a list of 5 instead of results of function calls?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `'(+ - * /)` is a list of symbols, not a list of functions. Symbols implement `AFn` and when supplied with two arguments, the function attempts to look up the symbol in the first argument (`2` here) and returns the second argument (`5` here) if the lookup fails.

Comment: This is a more in depth answer to my question, complemented by solution provided by @bsvingen.

Answer (score 13):

This works: `(map #(% 2 5) [+ - * /])`

This does not: `(map #(% 2 5) '[+ - * /])`

Nor does this: `(map #(% 2 5) '(+ - * /))`

The reason is that when you do `'(+ - * /)`, you get a list of the symbols +, - * and /, not the functions to which they refer - the quote also applies to the values of the list.

Using a vector avoids this problem.

If you absolutely want a list, do `(map #(% 2 5) (list + - * /))`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a function in clojure that does exactly what you want: `juxt`: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/juxt

So your example would be

```
(def funcs (juxt + - * /))
(funcs 2 5)
```

If someone comes up with a good explanation why the `map` approach does not work I would like to hear that too.